# RegEx match() in Javascript does not produce result as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble working out why a regex in Javascript is not working how I would expect it to.

The pattern is as follows:

```
\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)
```

trying to match text in the following format:

```
[Learn more](https://www.example.com)
```

```js
const text = 'Lorem ipsum etc [Learn more](https://www.google.com), and produce costly [test link](https://www.google.com). [another test link](https://www.google.com).'

const regex = /\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/
const found = text.match(regex)
console.log(found)
```

I am expecting the value of found to be the following:

```
[
    "[Learn more](https://www.google.com)",
    "[test link](https://www.google.com)",
    "[another test link](https://www.google.com)"
]
```

But the value seems to be as follows:

```
[
    "[Learn more](https://www.google.com), and produce costly [test link](https://www.google.com). [another test link](https://www.google.com)",
    "Learn more](https://www.google.com), and produce costly [test link](https://www.google.com). [another test link",
    "https://www.google.com"
]
```

I've tried the /ig flags but this doesn't seem to work. I'm trying in a different application (RegExRX) and getting the expected result but in Javascript, I can't get it to produce the same result.

Comment: `regex = /\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/g` Make it non-greedy and use global

Comment: If you're writing a Markdown parser, there are libraries you can install that will do the job for you without having to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` quantifier is *greedy* and will "eat" as much of the source string as possible. You can use `.+?` instead:

```
const regex = /\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/
```

Better yet, instead of `.` match "not ]":

```
const regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/
```

Explicitly excluding the boundary characters can perform better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: The regex `\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)` should do.

The reason the original pattern doesn't work is because the `+` quantifier is "greedy" by default—it will try to match as many characters as possible. Therefore, `.+` means "as much of *anything except new line character* as possible". You can already tell that closing bracket fits the definition just fine.

To make it work properly, you have to say "as much of anything as possible, until the first closing bracket." To do that, you should either substitute `.+` by `[^\]]+` (`[^\)]+` for the second group), or  simply make the aforementioned quantifier not so greedy by appending it with `?`, which turns both capturing groups into `(.+?)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21606148)

Comment: @Bonatti I should point out that the original post does not have a direct question to answer.